Cant use a git remote repo with another server user
we have a git server, what is actually used with one user of the remote. So every developer uses ssh://git@gitserver/gitdir/repoX.git to access this remote. Now its necessary to give access to a guest developer to only one special repo (repo5).
My way was to add a linux-user (guestdev) on gitserver and to add an extra usergroup (repo5group). Both users (git and guestdev) are added to repo5group.
Then I chowned the repo5 recursivly to repo5group and set the group suid flag recursivly to all folders in repo5. The accessrights of all content of repo5 is set to rw for group.
Now guestdev has full access to the content of repo5 in the filesystem and if something is created in his/her session, it will get the same permissions.
When I try to locally clone the ssh://git@gitserver/gitdir/repo5.git, everything works like expected, but when I clone with ssh://guestdev@gitserver/gitdir/repo5.git I get the following error:
fatal: detected dubious ownership in repository at '/gitdir/repo5.git'
To add an exception for this directory, call:

        git config --global --add safe.directory /gitdir/repo5.git
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

Ofcourse I could do the git config as suggested. But I want to understand, whats the problem. Maybe this is also the complete wrong way to give a second user access to one special repo and you have a easier and more elegant way to do it.
We use plane git from bash.
the config in the remote bare repo looks as follows:
[core]
        repositoryformatversion = 0
        filemode = true
        bare = true
        sharedRepository = group
[receive]
        denynonfastforwards = true


Thank you.

git config --global --add safe.directory /gitdir/repo5.git
Didn't change anything.

I think I've found half the answer.
The git manual says:
git init...
--shared[=(false|true|umask|group|all|world|everybody|<perm>)]
    Specify that the Git repository is to be shared amongst several
    users. This allows users belonging to the same group to push 
    into that repository.

@phd thank to phd
stackoverflow.com/a/69193032/7976758
All the steps I've done have been right:
Init with --bare --shared or,
if remote exists,chown -R :<groupname> repo.git
and set git config core.sharedRepository group (group is the value, dont use the groups name here)
and git config receive.denyNonFastForwards true at remote.
And if the repo existed, check the groups permission, maybe you need to
chmod -R g+rwX repo (dirs full accessable for group and files rw accessable and executable, if they have been executable as user, for group)
and find ./example6.git -type d -exec chmod g+s '{}' \+
(dirs should inherit their behavior)
Last step was the problem. The new user has to add the repos dir to its personal global .gitconfig:
git config --global --add safe.directory /path/to/remote/repo.git
I did it at the local developement machine (Windows11 with gitbash), which clones the remote repo by ssh.
But I'd rather to do it at the remote machine, logged in as the new user.
The safe.directory-entry needs to be in the home of the new user at the remote machine (where the bare server repo exists).

Feel free to edit your previous post so that the entire answer is all together in one place.

Thanks for this. I have a similar git server setup. I didn't know the command had to be run on the server, but it makes sense to require it there from a security standpoint.
